# Are there noteworthy functional properties of the exponential integral?

Tags: special-functions

I noticed that the following [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

$$\mbox{Ei}(x) := - \int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \,\mathrm d t$$

occurs increasingly in different areas of physics and in mathematics.

I am wondering if anyone knows of any interesting functional or algebraic properties it possesses that might make its applications more efficient. After scouring different sources I have not found any, but have seen it trivially related to other functions such as the incomplete gamma function or the sine and cosine integrals.

Comment: I did not find exactly what you ask for.  But I will provide two general answers anyway.

Comment: Thank you for bringing these up. While these are interesting, I am hoping for something more along the lines of useful functional properties like f(x+1)=xf(x) or f(x+y)=f(x)f(y), information that can more precisely point-point the nature of the function and how it can be used without directly relying on an analytic representation.

Answer (score 5):

One place to look on questions like this is the [Wolfram Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com) site.

The entry [ExpIntegralEi](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/) has 183 formulas.

Here are two examples:

> [image: image1]
>
> [image: image2]

Comment: The formulas for sin(x+y) and the like are in the Transformations section of the page for sin, but there’s nothing really like that on the page for Ei.

Answer (score 5):

Another place to look on questions like this is the [NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov)

[Here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6) is `Chapter 6 Exponential, Logarithmic, Sine, and Cosine Integrals`

Some examples, in terms of the related exponential integral $E_1(z) = \int_z^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\;dt$

continued fraction

> [image: continued fraction]

integrals

> [image]  [image]

At the end they discuss methods of computation, approximations, and software.